# Posting Tweet Twython 3.1.0 and Python 3.3.2 on OSX

Tags: python-3.x, osx-mavericks, twython

I am new to Python, and thought learning with Twitter would be useful to me. 
I put the following code together via researching code on the internet.

```
import sys
from twython import Twython

CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxx"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxx"
ACCESS_TOKEN = "xxxx"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "xxxx"

twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SEC$

twitter.update_status(status=sys.argv[1])
```

When I go to run the code I get errors, can anyone help? the errors are below:

```
$ python3 Twitter_Test_Put.py Test From Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Twitter_Test_Put.py", line 12, in <module>
   twitter.update_status(status=sys.argv[1])
  File                 "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/sit      e-packages/twython-3.1.0-py3.3.egg/twython/endpoints.py", line 90, in update_status
  File     "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/sit      e-packages/twython-3.1.0-py3.3.egg/twython/api.py", line 234, in post
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/sit      e-packages/twython-3.1.0-py3.3.egg/twython/api.py", line 224, in request
  File      "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/sit      e-packages/twython-3.1.0-py3.3.egg/twython/api.py", line 194, in _request
  twython.exceptions.TwythonAuthError: Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), An   error occurred processing your request.
```

Any help will be much appreciated, I am a new to all of this so easy steps to follow will be great thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Do you have an actual consumer key and secret?  Or are you literally using "xxxx" as shown above and not simply blocking them out since you shouldn't share them?

Comment: HI all, please excuse my post, I have worked it out, it was something to do with the authentication and not defining the OAUTH information.

Comment: @user2980552 Have you figured out what was the problem? I got the same error.